# Remove part of the string ever if not contain

Tags: lua

I am using MUSHClient and my script language is Lua. I would like to create a trigger that intercepts two posibilities:

```
1) HP:235 EP:235 >> Rider is in good shape.
2) Rider is in good shape.
```

I would like to get in this case 'Rider' as a variable, right now I got something like this:

```
* is in good shape.
```

Thing is that sometimes is getting the whole thing: `HP:235 EP:235 >> Rider` and its not what I need.

Any hint on this?

Thanks!

Comment: `local s = "HP:235 EP:235 >> Rider is in good shape."; local name = s:gsub(".*>>%s*", ""):match"^(.-) is in good shape%.$"`

Comment: Even though you have a solution, you should include some information in your question, such as what you have tried so far